# Invalid field servicing_Date__c for SObject Vehical1__c

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="VehicalServicingController">
    
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Vehical Details" columns="1">
        <apex:inputText label="Name" value="{!veh.Name}"/>
        <apex:inputText label="Vehical Number" value="{!veh.Vehical_Number__c}" />
        <apex:inputField label="Registeration Date" value="{!veh.Registeration_Date__c}" />
        <apex:inputField label="Vehical Expire Date" value="{!veh.Expiry_Date__c}"/>
        
        <apex:outputField label="Number of Days to Expire" value="{!veh.Number_of_days_to_Expire__c}"   />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
            
         <!--<apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter the Details for Servicing">   
        <apex:inputField value="{!serv.}"/> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!serv.Servicing_Date__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!serv.Vehical_Meter_Reading__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!serv.Insurance_No__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!serv.Servicing_Ammount__c}"/>
        
         </apex:pageBlockSection> -->
            
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveParent}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Vehical List 1">
            <apex:dataTable value="{!vehList}" var="vehValue"  id="theVechicalTable" width="120%">
            
                <apex:column headerValue="Vehical ID"><apex:outputText value="{!vehValue.Id}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="VehicalName"><apex:outputText value="{!vehValue.Name}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="VehicalNumber"><apex:outputText value="{!vehValue.Vehical_Number__c}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Servicing Id"><apex:outputText value="{!vehValue.Id}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Vehical Id "><apex:outputText value="{!vehValue.Name}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Servicing Date"><apex:outputText value="{!vehValue.servicing_Date__c}"/></apex:column> 
                <apex:column headerValue="Insurance Number"><apex:outputText value="{!vehValue.Insurance_No__c}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Servicing Amount"><apex:outputText value="{!vehValue.Servicing_Ammount__c}"/></apex:column>
            </apex:dataTable>
        
        
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class VehicalServicingController {
    
    public Vehical1__c veh{get;set;}
    
    public Servicing__c serv{get;set;}
   
    
    public VehicalServicingController(){
        veh = new Vehical1__c();
        Servicing__c serv1 = new Servicing__c();
    }

    public void saveParent(){
        system.debug('Button cliked'+veh);
        
    }
    public List<Vehical1__c> getvehList(){
        List<Vehical1__c> vList = new List<Vehical1__c>();
        vList = [Select Id, Name, Vehical_Number__c,
                 (SELECT Id,Name,Servicing__c.Servicing_Date__c,Servicing__c.Insurance_No__c,Servicing__c.Servicing_Ammount__c from Servicings__r)
                 from Vehical1__c];
        return vList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion that you should probably spell 'vehicle' and 'registration' and 'amount' correctly before your code makes it to production.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the code you provided, your error is because of this line:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Servicing Date">
    <apex:outputText value="{!vehValue.servicing_Date__c}"/>
</apex:column>
```

The `Vehical1__c` object does not have this `servicing_Date__c` field on it, the related `Servicing__c` object does.